# Create Qgis exe after successfully built complete using msvc 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I had build Qgis successfully using source code 2.8.3 in visual studio 2010.

Now i want to create exe of this built.

Does any one tell me how to create exe of Qgis.

Thanks

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project in "Solution explorer" on the left hand
   side
2. Click "Build"
3. Read the output for the file path to the exe created, as long as you
   have no compilation errors.

Comment: Hi Sam thanks,

Actually, my build is complete and its working fine using INSTALL. No I want to make installer file so that it can be installed on other system. Can you help me in making this.

Thanks

Comment: Ah you definitely need to use the word "installer" in the question, I'm afraid that is beyond my experience.